# Recursive function to delete nested categories in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have this table

```
id - parent_id - name 
1 - 0 - T-shirts 
2 - 1 - Red T-shirts 
3 - 1 - Black T-shirts 
4 - 0 - Sweaters 
5 - 4 - Red Sweaters 
6 - 4 - Blue
```

There can be six nested categories

recursive function that delete all nested categorie by parent id when i choose to delete an id

example when i delete tshirt , both red t-shirt and black-tshirt should be deleted to and there nested categorie
Mohamed Amine
i write those function but there blocking page
Mohamed Amine
to take all the ids i want to delete and store in an array to destroy all togather in once

voila functions

---

```
protected $theArray = array();

public function recursiveDelete($v)
{
  $toRecurses = Car::where('parent_id', $v )->get();
  foreach( $toRecurses as $toRecurse ){
    array_push( $this->theArray, $toRecurse->id );
  }
  foreach( $toRecurses as $toRecurse ){
    if( Car::where('parent_id' , $toRecurse->id)->get()->first() ){
      return $this->recursiveDelete( $toRecurse );
      //dd( Car::where('parent_id' , $toRecurse->id)->get()->first() );
    }
  }
}

public function testForDeletingCar(Car $carD, $id)
{
  $c = $carD::where('id' , $id)->get()->first();
  $this->recursiveDelete( $c->id );
  return $this->theArray;
}
```

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that the Model name is `Category` .. within the model class add the following method [`category.php` file]:

```
public function children(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

Within the controller class `CategoryController.php` use the following code

```
public function destroy($id){
    // Getting the parent category
    $parent = \App\Category::findOrFail($id);
    // Getting all children ids
    $array_of_ids = $this->getChildren($parent);
    // Appending the parent category id
    array_push($array_of_ids, $id);
    // Destroying all of them
    \App\Category::destroy($array_of_ids);
}

private function getChildren($category){
    $ids = [];
    foreach ($category->children as $cat) {
        $ids[] = $cat->id;
        $ids = array_merge($ids, $this->getChildren($cat));
    }
    return $ids;
}
```

Comment: that will not work for a tree 
every branch have in her parent id = the id of her parent

Answer (score 0):

```
public function destroy(Category $category)
{
    $rel=Category::query();
    // The bottom condition checked until -
    // no more same number in the "parent" column with the "id" column

    if ($e=$rel->where('parent', $category->id)->count()){
       
        alert()->error('First, the sub Categories must be deleted');
        return back();
    }else {

        $category->delete();
        alert()->success('Deleted successfully);
        return back();
    }

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).